# iphone autorotate issue

Tags: iphone, ios4, uitabbarcontroller, autorotate

I am using custom tabbar(3 tabs) in my application. each tabs are controlled by navigation controller as shown below. The issue is when on autorotate orientation, each autorotation takes fine on root controller but child controller (shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation) is not responding.

```
NSMutableArray *localControllersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:3];

UINavigationController *localNavigationContriller;

  XXXViewController *mail;
  xxx = [[XXXViewController alloc] initWithTabBar];

  localNavigationContriller=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:xxx];
  [localNavigationContriller.navigationBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleDefault];
  localNavigationContriller.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:134/255.0 green:187/255.0 blue:34/255.0 alpha:1];
  [localControllersArray addObject:localNavigationContriller];
  [localNavigationContriller release];
  [xxx release];

  YYYViewController *rsvn;
  yyyy = [[YYYViewController alloc] initWithTabBar];


  localNavigationContriller=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:yyyy];
  [localNavigationContriller.navigationBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleDefault];
  localNavigationContriller.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:134/255.0 green:187/255.0 blue:34/255.0 alpha:1];
  [localControllersArray addObject:localNavigationContriller];
  [localNavigationContriller release];
  [yyyy release];


  TempController *tem;
  tem = [[TempController alloc] initWithTabBar];


  localNavigationContriller=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:calendar];
  [localNavigationContriller.navigationBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleDefault];
  localNavigationContriller.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:134/255.0 green:187/255.0 blue:34/255.0 alpha:1];
  [localControllersArray addObject:localNavigationContriller];
  [localNavigationContriller release];


  tabBarController.delegate=self;
  tabBarController.viewControllers = localControllersArray;

  [localControllersArray release];
```

Comment: try using the code feature of the editor on here.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has specific guide to this situation:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CombiningViewControllers/CombiningViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH104-SW8

...have you tried following Apple's setup?

Your source code above is impossible, it would never compile. Your description of the problem is incomplete (*which* root controller is failing? The root nav, or the root tab?).

But ... try adding:

```
shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation
```

to *every* one of your controllers, and make each one do NSLog. Usually, you'll find that one of them (unexpectedly) is getting that message, but none of its children are. That usually means you failed to tell it about some of its children, but you should be able ot narrow it down.